# F# project types in Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded VS2017 to v15.5 today and I'm no longer able to create an F# project that uses plain old .NET Framework. The main options that I now see are:

- Console App (.NET Core)
- Class Library (.NET Standard)

There are also a bunch of other project types under .NET Core.
I'm working in an existing solution with projects that target .NET Framework 4.6.1, so I'd like to create a new project that's consistent with these. Also, I'd like the option of using WPF and other Windows-specific features. Is that no longer possible with F#?

Answer (score 6):

Found the problem: I had "F# language support" installed, but needed to add "F# desktop language support" in 15.5. It looks like the installer deselects this option by default, even when upgrading an installation that actually has these project types.

Comment: Could you update answer that by default Visual Studio installer deselects "F# desktop support" even you had installed it before? I've gone through the update yesterday myself and caught it only b/c after upgrade I decided to modify VS installation and see what new modules has been introduced.

Comment: Done.  (Extra text to make SO happy.)